# GIT Local and Remote Workflow

Tags: git, github

I am in the process of learning GIT. I setup an account with GitHub and my question is simply about local and remote workflow and how I can organize my local repo to emulate my remote. e.g.

I have a folder on my PC called Projects. I have sub folders in this projects such as Linux and Python.

Basically, I want to know how I should setup my projects (if needed) and repositories on GitHub to emulate my local GIT workflow.

Should I create a GIT repo locally in the root of Projects or just in the sub directories? Also, how would I manage this on GitHub as they do not have a folder structure that goes more than just one level deep. Github.com/username/projects or Github.com/python? I am not sure about how this works on GitHub.

OR what about when I have multiple Python projects I am working on, locally, I would create a sub-folder for each. Projects > Python > Program 1... Program 2...

Your help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello Matt, from my experience it is best to have a separate git repository for each project. Can you explain in more detail what you mean with "your git workflow"?

Comment: Basically, on my local machine of have a Projects directory, which includes two sub directories Python and Linux. In the PYthon folder, I will have sub-folders for Python projects. In the Linux Folder I will have sub-folders for different Linux bash files. So, on Github. Let's take the Python folder. Should I create a repo for the Python folder or a repo for each Python project folder on GitHub? What is the difference between a project and a standard repo?

Comment: Ok, I see... well in that case, if a "project" is something like a single shell script or Python script, then I'd go for one git repository where you put all your Linux and Python scripts in. You can create a git repository and then add your whole folder and files structure to it. A git repository has no limit regarding subfolders. So on GitHub you'd have just one repository with all your scripts/projects in it.

Comment: But with sub folders, all of my separate projects would be on the same master branch, correct?

Comment: Yes that's correct. I think it depends on what you want to achieve. If you have a big collection of scripts, which you want to have under version control, then one repository might be a good and simple approach. If each of your projects consists of many files and you plan to share these projects with other people, etc, then separate repositories would be more convenient. Please note that this is just my opinion.

Comment: I agree. I will stick to the separate repository approach. Thank you for your help.

Comment: How do I mark a solution?

Comment: You can't mark a comment *as* the solution; only *answers* can be checked like that. This is a bit unfortunate here as you'll need to get @Sky to write it up as an answer before you can give credit.

Comment: @sky If you wish to post an official solution, I will mark it as the answer. It's up to you.

Comment: @MattPaolini Thanks, but it's fine. Our discussion didn't feel like a "real solution" to me. Anyways, I'm glad you know how to go on now and hope you'll enjoy learning git - it's absolutely worth learning. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is opinion-based and depends largely on the actual use case.

If these projects are independent of each other, I advise to use separate repositories. This way you can manage access (public/private/collaborators) for each project separately and independently. Also, a repository will accumulate a history (of commits) that you might want to preserve. Once you have multiple projects in the same repository it is almost impossible to separate the projects later while preserving their history.

In case you are developing a project involving several sub-projects that directly depend on each other (like frontend/backend) I would use one repository. Another example where a common repository would make sense IMHO is for very small projects e.g. homework exercises (one repository per class).

As Sky mentions in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67547254/git-local-and-remote-workflow#comment119397832_67547254), in case you just have a personal collection of scripts in the sub-directories that should just be under version control, you can use a single repository for them.